# Using Excel LEFT Function to use multiple characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I apologize if this has been asked already but I could not find an answer.

I am working on combining multiple spreadsheets into one and we have a column for our offices. The offices are layed out to show the main office followed by the sub office after a slash if any exist. I am using the "LEFT" formula to pick out the main office from the sub office using the slash.

Example: Info Tech/Server

Formula: =LEFT(A2,SEARCH("/",A2)-1)

However some of the areas don't have a sub office and because there isn't a "/", excel will return a #VALUE! error on those items. Is there someway to use the formula to check for that slash and if not found then just use the entire string?

Comment: `=LEFT(A2,SEARCH("/",A2&"/")-1)`

Comment: Alternatively, select "Data" -> "Text to Columns" and choose "/" as your de-limiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method:

=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,SEARCH("/",A2)-1);A2)

Comment: This worked! Thank you, I didn't know that IFERROR was a thing, I'm still new to using excel however.